# Android how to perform click , long click and swipe operations(left to right , right to left , down to up , up to down) programmitically below api 24

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

**I am not able to find any suitable example/solution where I can perform click, long click and swipe operation programmatically for below api 24. Where I'll have to pass coordinates value and it'll perform click, long click and swipe operations.**

eg. if I send swipe coordinates from remote. it should perform swipe whatever the current screen is.

I am able to achieve this using accessibilityService above api 23. I also found some where that we can achieve this using INJECT_EVENT permission. but this permission is given to system level apps only.

I found AnyDesk app is also achieving the same thing with below api 24 and also found it is also using INJECT_EVENT permission but it is not a system app.

After lots of struggle finally posting a question of stackoverflow. 
Please help me..